# MS Access is looking for altered, strange source query name, with additional string attached at the end (and cannot find it)

Tags: ms-access

When I run a query "q_Query" what relates to other query named "q_Alokacje" it shows an error message, that it cannot find query called q_Alokacje_LONG_STRING_OF_DIGITS_AND_LETTERS.

[image]

The query q_Alokacje exist. In Design and SQL View of "q_Query" I use only "q_Alokacje".

I tried "Compact and Repair" and also -Decompile. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied all objects (tables, queries, forms and modules) to a clean empty Access database file. Now it seams to be fine.

(Copy the SQL, delete and recreate the query used to help for a while. After couple extensive calculaitons the error returns.)

Answer (score 1):

This can happen, Access sometimes makes temporary copies of queries and relates existing queries to those. In MSysObjects, you can find temporary copies of queries/tables quite often.

The fix is quite simple: copy the SQL, delete and recreate the query. Note that query properties (column widths among others) are lost in this process.